# Tikz: joining points on a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following figure

[image]

I would like to draw portions of circles between some of the red points. More explicitly, I would like to go from ac1 to ab1 and then to ac2 following circle A, then go to bc1 following circle C and to ab2 following circle B and back to ac1 following circle A.

There is probably a solution using the `arc` operation, but this would require computing the angles for every portion of circle, which can get tedious. Is there a simple way to do that ?

(I was thinking maybe drawing circles with `\clip`, but I can't figure out how to do it)

Here is my example code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (-1,-1);
\coordinate (c) at (1,-1);

\draw[name path=circleA] (a) circle (1.5cm);
\draw[name path=circleB] (b) circle (1.5cm);
\draw[name path=circleC] (c) circle (1.5cm);

\fill [red, name intersections={of=circleA and circleB,name=intAB}]
(intAB-1) circle (2pt) node[above left] {ab1}
(intAB-2) circle (2pt) node[below right] {ab2};
\fill [red, name intersections={of=circleA and circleC,name=intAC}]
(intAC-1) circle (2pt) node[above right] {ac1}
(intAC-2) circle (2pt) node[below left] {ac2};
\begin{scope}
\clip (a) circle (1.5cm);
\fill [red, name intersections={of=circleB and circleC,name=intBC}]
(intBC-1) circle (2pt) node[below] {bc1}
(intBC-2) circle (2pt) node {bc2};
\end{scope}

\node (A) at ($(a)+(0,1)$) {$A$};
\node (B) at ($(b)+(-1,0)$) {$B$};
\node (C) at ($(c)+(1,0)$) {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Clips are certainly an easy way to do this, how "clean" do you want the joins to be?

Comment: In the final document I may not draw the intersection points, so it would be nice if the joints were clean enough so that the line appears continuous.

Comment: In which case clipping is not the best option.  That's useful to know.

Comment: @AndrewStacey With `\pgfpatharcto` the joints are perfectly clean, so from a practical point of view I am happy with this solution. However, if you have another method with clips, even if joints do not match so well, I would be glad to have a look at the difference and learn something new..

Comment: Always worth learning!  If no-one else beats me to it (and, everyone else, please do!) then I'll add a clip solution next time I'm on a "proper" computer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

Here's a solution that uses the `nodes` that you have defined and the commands

```
\pgfpointanchor{<node>}{<anchor>}
\pgfpathmoveto{<coordinate>}
\pgfpatharcto{<x-radius>}{<y-radius>}{<rotation>}{<large arc flag>}{<counterclockwise flag>}{<target point>}
```

The idea is to use `\pgfpointanchor` to get the coordinates of one the points of intersection. You then use `pgfpathmoveto` to move there, and then use `\pgfpatharcto` to draw an arc to the other point of intersection (which you find the coordinates of using `\pgfpointanchor` again). All of these commands are detailed in [the pgf manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

The new piece I have added to your code is:

```
% new bit
\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}
% path between ac1 and ab1
\pgfsetstrokecolor{blue}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{intAC-1}{south}}
\pgfpatharcto{1.5cm}{1.5cm}{0}{0}{1}{\pgfpointanchor{intAB-1}{south}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
% path between ab1 and ac2
\pgfsetstrokecolor{red}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{intAB-1}{south}}
\pgfpatharcto{1.5cm}{1.5cm}{0}{0}{1}{\pgfpointanchor{intAC-2}{south}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
% path between ac2 and bc1
\pgfsetstrokecolor{green}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{intAC-2}{south}}
\pgfpatharcto{1.5cm}{1.5cm}{0}{0}{0}{\pgfpointanchor{intBC-1}{south}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
% path between bc1 and ab2
\pgfsetstrokecolor{yellow}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{intBC-1}{south}}
\pgfpatharcto{1.5cm}{1.5cm}{0}{0}{0}{\pgfpointanchor{intAB-2}{south}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
% path between ab2 and ac1
\pgfsetstrokecolor{orange}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{intAB-2}{south}}
\pgfpatharcto{1.5cm}{1.5cm}{0}{0}{1}{\pgfpointanchor{intAC-1}{south}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
```

Note that some of the paths are traversed clockwise, and some counter clockwise, determined by the `5th` argument to `\pgfpatharcto`

Here's the complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (-1,-1);
\coordinate (c) at (1,-1);

\draw[name path=circleA] (a) circle (1.5cm);
\draw[name path=circleB] (b) circle (1.5cm);
\draw[name path=circleC] (c) circle (1.5cm);

\fill [red, name intersections={of=circleA and circleB,name=intAB}]
(intAB-1) circle (2pt) node[above left] {ab1}
(intAB-2) circle (2pt) node[below right] {ab2};
\fill [red, name intersections={of=circleA and circleC,name=intAC}]
(intAC-1) circle (2pt) node[above right] {ac1}
(intAC-2) circle (2pt) node[below left] {ac2};
\begin{scope}
\clip (a) circle (1.5cm);
\fill [red, name intersections={of=circleB and circleC,name=intBC}]
(intBC-1) circle (2pt) node[below] {bc1}
(intBC-2) circle (2pt) node {bc2};
\end{scope}
% new bit
\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}
% path between ac1 and ab1
\pgfsetstrokecolor{blue}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{intAC-1}{south}}
\pgfpatharcto{1.5cm}{1.5cm}{0}{0}{1}{\pgfpointanchor{intAB-1}{south}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
% path between ab1 and ac2
\pgfsetstrokecolor{red}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{intAB-1}{south}}
\pgfpatharcto{1.5cm}{1.5cm}{0}{0}{1}{\pgfpointanchor{intAC-2}{south}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
% path between ac2 and bc1
\pgfsetstrokecolor{green}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{intAC-2}{south}}
\pgfpatharcto{1.5cm}{1.5cm}{0}{0}{0}{\pgfpointanchor{intBC-1}{south}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
% path between bc1 and ab2
\pgfsetstrokecolor{yellow}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{intBC-1}{south}}
\pgfpatharcto{1.5cm}{1.5cm}{0}{0}{0}{\pgfpointanchor{intAB-2}{south}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
% path between ab2 and ac1
\pgfsetstrokecolor{orange}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{intAB-2}{south}}
\pgfpatharcto{1.5cm}{1.5cm}{0}{0}{1}{\pgfpointanchor{intAC-1}{south}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}

\node (A) at ($(a)+(0,1)$) {$A$};
\node (B) at ($(b)+(-1,0)$) {$B$};
\node (C) at ($(c)+(1,0)$) {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this is what I was looking for. I wasn't aware of the command `\pgfpatharcto`, which is very useful indeed.

Answer (score 23):

**Edit:** *a new version with better jonctions... and new `atan2`*

This is not the first question that asks how to draw an arc between two points on a circle with known center. So I decided to create two new styles to meet this need. Here is an example of use:

```
\draw (a) to[clockwise arc centered at=c] (b);
```

This command draws an arc starting at `a`, ending at `b`, and centered at `c` (in fact, ending is on a line through `c` and `b` if `b` is not on the circle centered at `c` and that goes through `a`).

There are two styles: `clockwise arc centered at` and `anticlockwise arc centered at`.

(Due to rounding errors, always use `line join=round` to get better connections between some arcs.)

Here's your answer (I slightly modified the code of your MWE) using both styles:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\tikzset{
  anticlockwise arc centered at/.style={
    to path={
      let \p1=(\tikztostart), \p2=(\tikztotarget), \p3=(#1),
      \n{anglestart}={atan2(\y1-\y3,\x1-\x3)},
      \n{angletarget}={atan2(\y2-\y3,\x2-\x3)},
      \n{angletarget}={\n{angletarget} < \n{anglestart} ? \n{angletarget}+360 : \n{angletarget}},
      \n{radius}={veclen(\x1-\x3,\y1-\y3)}
      in arc(\n{anglestart}:\n{angletarget}:\n{radius})  -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
  },
  clockwise arc centered at/.style={
    to path={
      let \p1=(\tikztostart), \p2=(\tikztotarget), \p3=(#1),
      \n{anglestart}={atan2(\y1-\y3,\x1-\x3)},
      \n{angletarget}={atan2(\y2-\y3,\x2-\x3)},
      \n{angletarget}={\n{angletarget} > \n{anglestart} ? \n{angletarget} - 360 : \n{angletarget}},
      \n{radius}={veclen(\x1-\x3,\y1-\y3)}
      in arc(\n{anglestart}:\n{angletarget}:\n{radius})  -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % 3 centers (a, b, c)
  \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (b) at (-1,-1);
  \coordinate (c) at (1,-1);

  % 3 circles
  \draw[name path=circleA] (a) circle (1.5cm);
  \draw[name path=circleB] (b) circle (1.5cm);
  \draw[name path=circleC] (c) circle (1.5cm);

  % label of circles
  \node (A) at ($(a)+(0,1)$) {$A$};
  \node (B) at ($(b)+(-1,0)$) {$B$};
  \node (C) at ($(c)+(1,0)$) {$C$};

  % intersections of circles (A) and (B)
  \path [name intersections={of=circleA and circleB,name=AB}];
  % show them
  \fill[red] (AB-1) circle (2pt) node[above left] {AB-1};
  \fill[red] (AB-2) circle (2pt) node[below right] {AB-2};

  % intersections of circles (A) and (C)
  \path [name intersections={of=circleA and circleC,name=AC}];
  % show them
  \fill[red] (AC-1) circle (2pt) node[above right] {AC-1};
  \fill[red] (AC-2) circle (2pt) node[below left] {AC-2};

  % intersections of circles (B) and (C)
  \path[name intersections={of=circleB and circleC,name=BC}];
  % show them
  \fill[red] (BC-1) circle (2pt) node[above] {BC-1};
  \fill[red] (BC-2) circle (2pt) node[below] {BC-2};


  \draw[line join=round,orange,fill=orange,fill opacity=.5,line width=1pt]
  (AC-2)
  to[clockwise arc centered at=a] (AB-2)
  to[anticlockwise arc centered at=b] (BC-1)
  to[anticlockwise arc centered at=c] (AC-2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this, nice work :)

Comment: I think `atan2` has (y, x) and not (x, y) as parameters, so they need to be swapped in your answer.

Comment: @corvus_192 You are right... in 2022. In 2012, the x and y parameters were not yet reversed in TikZ ! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Even though [cmhughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6621/cmhughes) has already shown us [his version with `\pgfpatharcto`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71551/16595) I want to add a version that TikZ-ifies the `\pgfpatharcto` command under the new path operator `arc to`.

The code has been originally developed for [another question](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/1490/wie-kann-ich-mit-tikz-einen-kreisbogen-zwischen-zwei-punkten-zeichnen) on [TeXwelt.de](http://texwelt.de/wissen/) (German). The only difference is that it uses `arc to` instead of `arc*`.

With this operator, the required arc can be drawn (and filled) with

```
\draw (intAC-1) arc to [arc large] (intAC-2)
                arc to [arc cw]    (intBC-1)
                arc to [arc cw]    (intAB-2)
                arc to []          (intAC-1) -- cycle;
```

The options

- `arc large` and `arc small` (`<large arc flag>`) as well as
- `arc cw` and `arc ccw` (`<counterclockwise flag>`)

correspond to the flags of `\pgfpatharcto` (argument `#4` and `#5`).

The third argument is used for rotation and can be set with `arc rotation` (initially `0`).

As the precision of `\pgfpatharcto` is rather bad, the joined close (`-- cycle`) doesn’t look  so good with the default `miter` line join (but only at 6400 % zoom), I’d use `line join=round` where this imperfection disappears.

The path operator `arc to` misses a proper timer (the function that places nodes “along” the path), as a substitute it uses the timer of a straight line (`--`). The `[ ]` are mandatory (as can be seen at the fourth occurrence of `arc to`).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  arc/ccw/.initial=1,
  arc/large/.initial=0,
  arc ccw/.style={/tikz/arc/ccw=1},
  arc cw/.style={/tikz/arc/ccw=0},
  arc large/.style={/tikz/arc/large=1},
  arc small/.style={/tikz/arc/large=0},
  arc rotation/.initial=0
}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@arcA rc{\pgfutil@ifnextchar t%
  {\tikz@flush@moveto\tikz@arcB@opt}%  -> our new "arc to"
  {\tikz@flush@moveto\tikz@arc@cont}}% -> our old "arc"
\def\tikz@arcB@opt to#1[#2]{%
  \def\tikz@arcB@options{#2}
  \tikz@do@@arcB}
\def\tikz@do@@arcB{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar n{\tikz@collect@label@onpath\tikz@do@@arcB}
    {\pgfutil@ifnextchar c{\tikz@collect@coordinate@onpath\tikz@do@@arcB}
      {\tikz@scan@one@point\tikz@do@arcB}}}
\def\tikz@do@arcB#1{%
  \edef\tikz@timer@start{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}
  \tikz@make@last@position{#1}%
  \edef\tikz@timer@end{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}%
  \iftikz@shapeborder
    \edef\tikz@moveto@waiting{\tikz@shapeborder@name}%
  \fi
  \begingroup
    \tikzset{every arc/.try}%
    \expandafter\tikzset\expandafter{\tikz@arcB@options}%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/x radius}}%
    \let\tikz@arc@x\pgfmathresult
    \ifpgfmathunitsdeclared
      \edef\tikz@arc@x{\tikz@arc@x pt}%
    \else
      \pgf@process{\pgfpointxy{\tikz@arc@x}{0}}%
      \pgfmathveclen@{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
      \edef\tikz@arc@x{\pgfmathresult pt}%
    \fi
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/y radius}}%
    \let\tikz@arc@y\pgfmathresult
    \ifpgfmathunitsdeclared
      \edef\tikz@arc@y{\tikz@arc@y pt}%
    \else
      \pgf@process{\pgfpointxy{0}{\tikz@arc@y}}%
      \pgfmathveclen@{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
      \edef\tikz@arc@y{\pgfmathresult pt}%
    \fi
    \pgfpatharcto{\tikz@arc@x}{\tikz@arc@y}
                 {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc rotation}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc/large}}
                 {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc/ccw}}{#1}%
  \endgroup
  \let\tikz@timer=\tikz@timer@line
  \tikz@scan@next@command
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[radius=1.5]
\draw[name path=circleA] ( 0, 0) coordinate (a) circle [];
\draw[name path=circleB] (-1,-1) coordinate (b) circle [];
\draw[name path=circleC] ( 1,-1) coordinate (c) circle [];

\fill [red, name intersections={of=circleA and circleB,name=intAB}]
     (intAB-1) circle (2pt) node[above left]  {ab1}
     (intAB-2) circle (2pt) node[below right] {ab2};
\fill [red, name intersections={of=circleA and circleC,name=intAC}]
     (intAC-1) circle (2pt) node[above right] {ac1}
     (intAC-2) circle (2pt) node[below left]  {ac2};
\fill [red, name intersections={of=circleB and circleC,name=intBC}]
     (intBC-1) circle (2pt) node[above]       {bc1};


\node (A) at ([shift={((0,1)} ]a) {$A$};
\node (B) at ([shift={((-1,0)}]b) {$B$};
\node (C) at ([shift={((1,0)} ]c) {$C$};

\draw[
  thick,
  line join=round,
  draw=blue,
  fill opacity=.5,
  fill=blue!50
] (intAC-1) arc to [arc large] (intAC-2)
            arc to [arc cw]    (intBC-1)
            arc to [arc cw]    (intAB-2)
            arc to []          (intAC-1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old (relatively speaking!) question, but since it was asked then the [`spath3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) library has been developed that can handle this sort of thing quite simply.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71548/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,spath3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (-1,-1);
\coordinate (c) at (1,-1);

\draw[spath/save=circleA] (a) circle (1.5cm);
\draw[spath/save=circleB] (b) circle (1.5cm);
\draw[spath/save=circleC] (c) circle (1.5cm);

\tikzset{
  spath/remove empty components=circleA,
  spath/remove empty components=circleB,
  spath/remove empty components=circleC,
  spath/split at intersections={circleA}{circleB},
  spath/split at intersections={circleB}{circleC},
  spath/split at intersections={circleC}{circleA},
  spath/get components of={circleA}\cptsA,
  spath/get components of={circleB}\cptsB,
  spath/get components of={circleC}\cptsC,
}

\draw[
  red,
  thick,
  spath/use=\getComponentOf{\cptsA}{4},
  spath/use={\getComponentOf{\cptsA}{1},weld},
  spath/use={\getComponentOf{\cptsC}{1},weld,reverse},
  spath/use={\getComponentOf{\cptsB}{3},weld,reverse},
  spath/use={\getComponentOf{\cptsA}{3},weld},
  spath/close=current,
];

\fill [red, name intersections={of=circleA and circleB,name=intAB}]
(intAB-1) circle (2pt) node[above left] {ab1}
(intAB-2) circle (2pt) node[below right] {ab2};
\fill [red, name intersections={of=circleA and circleC,name=intAC}]
(intAC-1) circle (2pt) node[above right] {ac1}
(intAC-2) circle (2pt) node[below left] {ac2};
\begin{scope}
\clip (a) circle (1.5cm);
\fill [red, name intersections={of=circleB and circleC,name=intBC}]
(intBC-1) circle (2pt) node[below] {bc1}
(intBC-2) circle (2pt) node[above] {bc2};
\end{scope}

\node (A) at ($(a)+(0,1)$) {$A$};
\node (B) at ($(b)+(-1,0)$) {$B$};
\node (C) at ($(c)+(1,0)$) {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The three circles are split at the places where they intersect with each other and then various of the components are recombined to give the final path.  A couple of the components have to be reversed so that they join correctly.

[image: Combined path from segments of the circles.]

Answer (score 0):

With `tkz-euclide`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/a,-1/-1/b,1/-1/c,1.5/0/x,.5/-1/y,-.5/-1/z}
\tkzDrawCircles(a,x b,y c,z)
\tkzInterCC(a,x)(b,y) \tkzGetPoints{ab1}{ab2}
\tkzInterCC(a,x)(c,z) \tkzGetPoints{ac1}{ac2}
\tkzInterCC(b,y)(c,z) \tkzGetPoints{bc1}{bc2}
\tkzDrawPoints[red](ab1,ab2,ac1,ac2,bc1,bc2)
\tkzDrawArc[red,line width=1pt](a,ab1)(ac2)
\tkzDrawArc[red,line width=1pt](b,ab1)(bc1)
\tkzDrawArc[red,line width=1pt](c,bc1)(ac2)
\tkzDrawPoints[red](ab1,ab2,ac1,ac2,bc1,bc2)
\tkzLabelPoints[red,below right](ab1,ab2,ac1,ac2,bc1,bc2)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]