# Draw the proper angle arc

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I am trying to draw an arc to indicate angle between y axis and r line, but I don't seem to achive it. My code is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{kerkis}
%\usepackage{kmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{Darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.4,0}
\definecolor{Darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.4}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray,->] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[gray,->] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\draw[gray,dashed] (-5,4) -- (5,4);
\node at (5,0.2) {$x$};
\node at (-0.2,5) {$y$};

\fill (0,0) circle (2pt) node[below] (e) {$m,e$};
\fill (-3,4) circle (2pt) node[above] (ion) {$ze$};

\draw[red] (0,0) -- (-3,4);
\draw[gray,->] (4,1.75) -- (4,0);
\draw[gray,->] (4,2.25) -- (4,4);
\node at (4,2) {$b$};
\draw[blue,->] (-3,4) -- (-1.5,4);
\node[blue] at (-1.8,4.2) {$V$};
\node[red] at (-2.7,3) {$r$};

\draw[Darkgreen,->] (0,0) -- (-1.5,2);
\draw[Darkgreen,->] (0,0) -- (0,2);
\draw[Darkgreen,->] (0,0) -- (-1.5,0);
\draw[Darkgreen,very thin,dashed] (0,2) -- (-1.5,2);
\draw[Darkgreen,very thin,dashed] (-1.5,0) -- (-1.5,2);

\node[Darkgreen] at (0.3,2) {$F_y$};
\node[Darkgreen] at (-1.5,-0.3) {$F_x$};
\node[Darkgreen,left] at (-1.7,2) {$F=\dfrac{kze^2}{r^2}$};
%\draw[Darkgreen] (0.5,0.5) arc (80:123:0.8cm);
\draw[Darkgreen] (1cm,0cm) arc (90:125:1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My output is

[image]

Any ideas on that?

---

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you mean `\draw[Darkgreen] (0cm,1cm) arc (90:125:1cm);`? Looks like you have the x and y coordinates reversed.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: Yep that seems like an answer to me. Could also include `\pgfmathsetmacro{\EndAngle}{90+atan2(4,3)}` to compute the end angle as opposed to guess its value.

Comment: Look at [Tikz: joining points on a circle](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71548/14500) and my [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71596/14500).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you don't have to load `color` as `tikz` already loads `xcolor`. You have to put the things in this order though:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{Darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.4,0}
\definecolor{Darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.4}
```

Having said that, why to manually calculate the angles? Use `clip`. First draw a triangle (well almost a triangle)

```
\path[clip] (0,2) -- (0,0) -- (-3,4);
```

and then a circle:

```
\node[circle,draw=Darkgreen,minimum size=40pt] at (0,0) (circ) {};
```

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{kerkis}
%\usepackage{kmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{Darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.4,0}
\definecolor{Darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.4}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray,->] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[gray,->] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
\draw[gray,dashed] (-5,4) -- (5,4);
\node at (5,0.2) {$x$};
\node at (-0.2,5) {$y$};

\fill (0,0) circle (2pt) node[below] (e) {$m,e$};
\fill (-3,4) circle (2pt) node[above] (ion) {$ze$};

\draw[red] (0,0) -- (-3,4);
\draw[gray,->] (4,1.75) -- (4,0);
\draw[gray,->] (4,2.25) -- (4,4);
\node at (4,2) {$b$};
\draw[blue,->] (-3,4) -- (-1.5,4);
\node[blue] at (-1.8,4.2) {$V$};
\node[red] at (-2.7,3) {$r$};

\draw[Darkgreen,->] (0,0) -- (-1.5,2);
\draw[Darkgreen,->] (0,0) -- (0,2);
\draw[Darkgreen,->] (0,0) -- (-1.5,0);
\draw[Darkgreen,very thin,dashed] (0,2) -- (-1.5,2);
\draw[Darkgreen,very thin,dashed] (-1.5,0) -- (-1.5,2);

\node[color=Darkgreen] at (0.3,2) {$F_y$};
\node[Darkgreen] at (-1.5,-0.3) {$F_x$};
\node[Darkgreen,left] at (-1.7,2) {$F=\dfrac{kze^2}{r^2}$};
%% First clip 
\path[clip] (0,2) -- (0,0) -- (-3,4) -- cycle;
%%The circle 
\node[circle,draw=Darkgreen,minimum size=40pt] at (0,0) (circ) {};
%
%\draw[Darkgreen] (0.5,0.5) arc (80:123:0.8cm);
\draw[Darkgreen] (1cm,0cm) arc (90:125:1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

First coordinate determine star of arc. exchange line

```
\draw[Darkgreen] (1cm,0cm) arc (90:125:1cm);
```

with

```
\draw[Darkgreen] (0,1) arc (90:125:1cm);
```

and your (not MWE) example should draw arc in desired place (if I catch where the arc should be).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Reversing coordinates really works! But I can't understand why! The syntax is `\draw (P) arc (a:b:r)` (each variable can be seen on my edited answer). My idea was to put P on the x axis, (1,0) that is...