# tikz draw circle segment

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I use tikz to draw a circle segment if I have the center of the circle and two points on it? Please see the following example

[image: example]

Update:
I try to accomplish something like this. This can be done using the method from [Tikz: joining points on a circle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71548/tikz-joining-points-on-a-circle), but I would prefer a some sort of tikz solution, because this would allow me to use a tikz style.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You should have a look at [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71548/tikz-joining-points-on-a-circle). If it does not answer, your question please update it to describe how your problem is different.

Comment: yeah it works by using `\pgfpathmoveto{<coordinate>}` `\pgfpatharcto{<x-radius>}{<y-radius>}{<rotation>}{<large arc flag>}{<counterclockwise flag>}{<target point>}` and then translating by the center. But is there some more intuitive way to write this in tikz? It would be great if I could easily use this with `\filldraw[somestyle]`

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows which points you want to connect. There are a few ways to do this. For an arc there exists `arc[<opt>]`.

Comment: Sure I can create a MWE (tomorrow). In short: I have all the black points in the second figure, and want to create the green object.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Result]

Using `calc` library and the operators `let` and `in` you can compute the radius, initial angle and final angle for the `arc` from the three points you have (center and two circle points), and use then the computed numbers as part of the path. The following MWE shows how:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (center) at (3,3);
\coordinate (1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (2) at (5, .5);
\coordinate (3) at ($(center) +(30:2)$);
\coordinate (4) at ($(center) +(70:2)$);
\coordinate (5) at (0,6);

\draw[blue, dotted]
      let \p1 =  ($(3)-(center)$),
          \n0 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
      in (center) circle(\n0);


\filldraw[draw=black, fill=green, fill opacity=0.3]
   let \p1 = ($(3) - (center)$),
       \p2 = ($(4) - (center)$),
       \n0 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},            % Radius
       \n1 = {atan(\y1/\x1)+180*(\x1<0)},  % initial angle
       \n2 = {atan(\y2/\x2)+180*(\x2<0)}   % Final angle
    in
    (1) -- (2) --  (3) arc(\n1:\n2:\n0)  -- (5)  -- cycle;

\foreach \dot in {1,2,3,4,5,center} {
  \fill (\dot) circle(2pt);
  \node[above] at (\dot) {\dot};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you have v2.10 of pgf/tikz, you can calculate the initial and final angles using `atan2(x,y)` instead of the above expression, (thanks to [qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel) for suggesting it), i.e:

```
       \n1 = {atan2(\x1,\y1)},  % initial angle
       \n2 = {atan2(\x2,\y2)}   % Final angle
```

Comment: Now, I was unable to draw the arc in red... (in the same path operation, I mean)

Comment: There is `atan2(x,y)` for this: `\n1 = {atan2(\x1,\y1)}, \n2 = {atan2(\x2,\y2)`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I cannot find `atan2` in my pgf manual, and it does not work in my system nor in http://www.tlhiv.org/ltxpreview/ Is it a new feature?

Comment: It’s in v2.10. See [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) on page 5.3.4 (63.2.3 “Trigonometric functions”)