# Draw an arc using radius and angles up to specific point

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I have following code in TiKZ:

```
\documentclass[border=.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0, 0) circle (1cm);

\draw[rounded corners = .1cm] (200:1.2cm) arc (200:-20:1.2cm) -- (-20:2.2cm) arc (-20:200:2.2cm) -- cycle;
\draw[] (0,1.25cm) -- (0,2.15cm);

\draw[gray] (-.1cm,2.3cm) -- (-.1cm,3.5cm);
\draw[gray] (200:2.4cm) arc (200:90:2.4cm);
\draw[gray] (90:3.4cm) arc (90:200:3.4cm);

\draw[rounded corners = .1cm, red] (200:2.4cm) arc (200:90:2.4cm) -- (90:3.4cm) arc (90:200:3.4cm) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which result in the following picture:
[image]

But I need a slightly different image. I need red figure to follow gray vertical line (not at 90 degrees).

Any suggestions will highly appreciate.

Comment: You need to change start/end angle of red line accordingly. Both  angle you can calculate from geometry relations of this line to circle origin.

Comment: Maybe this can help to draw arcs to a specific point: [Q71548](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71548). Note, that you have to switch the arguments of `atan2` nowadays.

Comment: do you mean as a simple rotation?

Comment: @percusse not rotation. I need figure edge to follow gray line (e.g. be little bit shorter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you want? I use `\pgfgetlastxy` to get the `x` and `y` coordinates of the intersection points. Then I use `pgfmath` package to compute the polar angle of the intersection points.
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfmath,tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0, 0) circle (1cm);

\draw[rounded corners = .1cm] (200:1.2cm) arc (200:-20:1.2cm) -- (-20:2.2cm) arc (-20:200:2.2cm) -- cycle;
\draw[] (0,1.25cm) -- (0,2.15cm);

\draw[gray,name path=ver] (-.1cm,2.3cm) -- (-.1cm,3.5cm);
\draw[gray,name path=bot] (200:2.4cm) arc (200:90:2.4cm);
\draw[gray,name path=top] (90:3.4cm) arc (90:200:3.4cm);
\path[name intersections={of=top and ver,by=T}];
\path[name intersections={of=bot and ver,by=B}];
\path (T);\pgfgetlastxy{\XT}{\YT};
\path (B);\pgfgetlastxy{\XB}{\YB};
\pgfmathparse{atan2(\YT,\XT)}
\edef\topangle{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathparse{atan2(\YB,\XB)}
\edef\botangle{\pgfmathresult}

\draw[thick,rounded corners = .1cm, red] 
(200:2.4cm) arc (200:\botangle:2.4cm) -- (\topangle:3.4cm) arc (\topangle:200:3.4cm) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```